# How to Raise exceptions for a failed condition used in select statement of cursor

Tags: plsql

I am a plsql beginner, I found that i am not getting any error if i give an invalid data into select statement of cursor.
I want to raise an exception if the given data for condition not matches with data in table.Could anyone help me in how to check the condition in the begin block to raise exception.

Comment: Can you show us your code, along with an explanation of what you have tried so far ? A short reading of [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may help as well.

Answer (score 0):

You are not able to add any exception handling to the SQL within the Cursor.  Based on the limited knowledge gained from reading your question I have come up with the below.

My example shows you how to work with a Cursor and how to Declare your own Exceptions.  I'm using a CTE to create the fake data.  The Exception I am checking for are names that are too long.  When the Cursor pulls back first names that exceed 20 characters the `too_long` custom exception is raised.

I add the data that is pulled back from the Cursor to a collection.  Then, using an IF statement I check for the character lengths of the first names.  If any First Names are found to be greater than 20 characters Raise the `too_long` Exception.

```
DECLARE

  /* Declare Exception */
  too_long  EXCEPTION;

  /* Declare Cursor */
  CURSOR cur_my_fake_data IS
  WITH fake_data AS
  (
    SELECT 1001 AS p_key, 'Jacob Brian Anderson the First' AS f_name FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 1021 AS p_key, 'Bob' AS f_name FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 1025 AS p_key, 'Ryan' AS f_name FROM dual
  )

  SELECT p_key, f_name
  FROM fake_data
  ;

  TYPE t_my_fake_data IS TABLE OF cur_my_fake_data%ROWTYPE; /* Declare Type based off of Cursor */
  c_my_fake_data  t_my_fake_data  :=  t_my_fake_data();     /* Declare Collection and initialize it */

BEGIN

  /* Open Cursor and fill collection with data from Cursor */
  OPEN cur_my_fake_data;
    FETCH cur_my_fake_data BULK COLLECT INTO c_my_fake_data; /* Fill Collection with data from Cursor */
  CLOSE cur_my_fake_data;

  /* Loop thru collection */
  FOR r IN c_my_fake_data.FIRST .. c_my_fake_data.LAST
  LOOP
    IF LENGTH(c_my_fake_data(r).f_name) > 20 THEN
      dbms_output.put_line('LENGTH: ' || LENGTH(c_my_fake_data(r).f_name));
      RAISE too_long;
    END IF;
  END LOOP;

EXCEPTION

WHEN too_long THEN
    dbms_output.put_line('More Than 20 Characters');

WHEN OTHERS THEN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('Error '||TO_CHAR(SQLCODE)||': '||SQLERRM);
  CLOSE cur_my_fake_data;

END
;
```